# How to create a DataTable responsive filled from $.Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am developing an app which displays many information from a web-service query, the data-table fills the information correctly and it displays the style correctly too, but when I try to see the information in a mobile device the Data-table is looking very bad.

I am using `$.Ajax` method to fill the information.

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/enrollment.asmx/Searcher',
                data: JSON.stringify(JsonObj),
                contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#loadingDiv").hide();//Show Loader

                    var html = " <table id=\"db\" class=\"table-hover dt-responsive nowrap table table-bordered\"><thead><tr><th data-priority='1'>Selection</th><th>City</th><th>Zip</th><th>Address</th><th>State</th><th>ESIID</th><th>Utility</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        html = html + "<tr name='userinformation' onclick=\"rowSelected('" + data.d[i].SEnrollCity + data.d[i].SEnrollZip + data.d[i].SEnrollStreet + "');\" id='" + data.d[i].SEnrollCity + data.d[i].SEnrollZip + data.d[i].SEnrollStreet + "'><td><input type='radio' name='userinformation' value='#'></td></td><td id='" + data.d[i].SEnrollCity + data.d[i].SEnrollZip + data.d[i].SEnrollStreet + "/SEnrollCity'>" + data.d[i].SEnrollCity + "</td><td id='" + data.d[i].SEnrollCity + data.d[i].SEnrollZip + data.d[i].SEnrollStreet + "/SEnrollZip'>" + data.d[i].SEnrollZip + "</td><td id='" + data.d[i].SEnrollCity + data.d[i].SEnrollZip + data.d[i].SEnrollStreet + "/SEnrollStreet'>" + data.d[i].SEnrollStreet + "</td><td id='" + data.d[i].SEnrollCity + data.d[i].SEnrollZip + data.d[i].SEnrollStreet + "/SState'>" + data.d[i].SState + "</td><td id='" + data.d[i].SEnrollCity + data.d[i].SEnrollZip + data.d[i].SEnrollStreet + "/SEsiid'>" + data.d[i].SEsiid + "</td><td id='" + data.d[i].SEnrollCity + data.d[i].SEnrollZip + data.d[i].SEnrollStreet + "/SUtility'>" + data.d[i].SUtility + "</td></tr>";
                        _vDistributionServiceProviderID = data.d[i].SDistributionServiceProviderID;
                        _vStateCode = data.d[i].SStateCode;
                    }

                    console.log("Dis: " + _vDistributionServiceProviderID);

                    html = html + "</tbody></table>";
                    $("#dbResultTable").html(html);//We have the Append here
                    $("#lblCheck").show();

                    if ($('#db thead').length > 0) {
                        var table = $("#db").DataTable();
                        $(table).remove();
                        var table = $("#db").DataTable();
                        table.draw();
                    }
                    else {
                        var table = $("#db").DataTable();
                        table.draw();
                    }

                    $("#submit").show();
                    $("#lblSelection").show();
                    $("#lblSelectionInfo").show();
                    if (data.d.SError == "" || data.d.SError == null) {
                        //Write an error
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Error 1");
                        $("#divResult").html(data.d.SError);
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data.d.SError));
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    //alert("Error 2");
                    alert("The error is: " + JSON.stringify(e));
                    $("#divResult").html(data.d.SError);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data.d.SError));
                }
            });
```

Initialize the Data-table.

```
var table = $("#db").DataTable({
                            responsive: true,
                            columnDefs: [
                            { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
                            { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -1 }
                                                    ]
                        });
```

[image]

Unfortunately in the responsive device it look awful. Could somebody please help me this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: defines awful? could you provide an image or some description?

Comment: I have provided an img of it.

Comment: I suggest you to change data source instead of editing DOM

Comment: How should I change my data source?

Comment: Get the response from the server as json and parse it here. Then change the data source. using `fnAddData()`

Answer (score 0):

Your initial stage of data table

```
var table = $("#db").DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                columnDefs: [
               { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
               { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -1 }
                                                ]
            });
```

Get the data using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/enrollment.asmx/Searcher',
       data: JSON.stringify(JsonObj),
       success:function(data){
           var json=JSON.parse(data);
           table.fnClearTable();
           table.fnAddData(json);               
       }
    });
```